# Superimposing time data in excel

Tags: excel

So I want to make a load duration curve in excel. And I have the demand and the time for which the EV is active for a year. So basically I want to make a load curve for the whole year. My problem is that I only have like a starting and end time where the EV is active during the day and data does not show that it is zero elsewhere.

So I want to create a whole sheet with 24 hour times for 365 days using the data that I have.

My confusion is how to take the limited data that i have which starts at any time not on the hour to make a full 24 hr one year data for a load duration curve.

Comment: It would be useful to post some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In a chart with 365 days on the X axis, the distinction between different times of the day will be difficult to discern.

If you use a line chart you can set it to show empty cells as zero instead of connecting empty cells with a line.

If you want the line to drop to zero, you must have rows for that date with no data in the values column.